# Looking for the subject of an infinitive phrase

Tags: infinitive-phrases

From an [article on kiting](http://www.kiting.com/kiting.htm):

> Leading edge inflatable kites, known also as inflatables, LEI kites or C-kites, are typically made from ripstop polyester with an inflatable plastic bladder that spans the front edge of the kite with separate smaller bladders that are perpendicular to the main bladder **to form the chord or foil of the kite**.

As I understand, "*to form the chord or foil of the kite*" is an infinitive phrase (or clause). But what is its subject? What actually forms the foil, according to the sentence? The front-edge bladder? Or the smaller bladders? Or both? Is the sentence grammatical?

The sentence is also used in Wikipedia's [article on kitesurfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitesurfing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of the infinitive phrase is the *entire* phrase "with an inflatable.....with separate smaller ... to the main bladder".

I'd change "to form" to "forming" and set that "with...with..." clause off with commas, and stick in an "and".

> Leading edge inflatable kites, known also as inflatables, LEI kites or
>   C-kites, are typically made from ripstop polyester, with an inflatable
>   plastic bladder that spans the front edge of the kite **and** with separate
>   smaller bladders that are perpendicular to the main bladder, <del>to
>   form</del> forming the chord or foil of the kite.

But if given free reign (or even free rein), I'd put a full stop or semicolon after *polyester* and start a new sentence|independent clause.

P.S. With respect to the question is it grammatical -- No, it isn't. "to form" requires an antecedent clause with a *transitive* verb. These are grammatical:

> We *put* a thingamajig here, and a whatchamacallit there, *to form*
>   the gizmo.
>
> It *has* a thingamajig here, and a whatchamacallit there, *forming*
>   the gizmo.
>
> It's got a gadget, *with* a thingamajig and a whatchamacallit,
>   *forming* the gizmo.

[image]

Comment: I think it's essentially just "Separate smaller bladders being perpendicular to the main bladder forms the chord or foil of the kite." The larger structure is about "made from X with Y with Z that are J to form K".

Comment: Thanks for the note, @DamkerngT ! Am I correct to understand taht the smaller bladders are *perpendicular* in order to form the aerodynamic foil of the kite?

Comment: @CopperKettle It looks like so. To me, the writer means they are made perpendicular to form the foil. I'm not a kite expert, though.

Comment: I could agree with Damkerng T.  I was understanding the entire assembly, i.e. the front span with its perpendicular bladders, as the "foil".  But I'd still keep the suggested edits.