# Are 'chord' and 'foil' synonymous in this excerpt?

Tags: word-meaning

From an [article on kiting](http://www.kiting.com/kiting.htm):

> Leading edge inflatable kites, known also as inflatables, LEI kites or C-kites, are typically made from ripstop polyester with an inflatable plastic bladder that spans the front edge of the kite with separate smaller bladders that are perpendicular to the main bladder to form the **chord or foil** of the kite.

Earlier today I asked [a question on what is it exactly](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37991/looking-for-the-subject-of-an-infinitive-phrase) that forms the **chord or foil** (according to the sentence): the bladder configuration as a whole or the smaller bladders only.

Now I want to confirm or refute my gut feeling that "chord" and "foil" are used synonymously here. I beleive they are, since the coordinating conjunction **or** is placed between them, meaning the sentence could be rephrased as:

> The configuration of bladders forms the characteristic of the kite called "chord" or "foil".

In what other way could the use of **OR** be interpreted? That the bladder configuration sometimes forms the cord and in other instances forms the foil of the kite? That's illogical.

Moreover, citing from the Wikipedia article on [Airfoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airfoil):

> The chord line is the straight line connecting leading and trailing edges. The chord length, or simply **chord**, c, is the length of the chord line. That is the **reference dimension** of the airfoil section.

It feels like **chord** could be used synonymously with **(air)foil**.

Comment: I suspect the kiting article, in using the terms as synonyms, is using the term *chord* loosely. http://er.jsc.nasa.gov/seh/c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to confirm or refute my gut feeling that "chord" and "foil" are used synonymously here.

You are correct.

> In what other way could the use of OR be interpreted? That the bladder configuration sometimes forms the cord and in other instances forms the foil of the kite? That's illogical.

While "X or Y" can be used to express that the subject can be in one of different, valid statuses (e.g. John came home and he is hungry or tired) it's also used to express that the subject can be called one of various valid names - in what I would say is an "educational context."

So ...

> Leading edge inflatable kites, known also as inflatables, LEI kites or C-kites

sounds like a dictionary or schoolbook definition, so that is what cues me in to understand "forms the chord or foil" is two names for the same concept.

I know nothing of kites so without that cue I might be as confused as you until I researched. :)

Comment: But they *are* different.  The *chord* is the line between the leading edge and the trailing edge of an airfoil.  *foil* is short for airfoil and refers to the a wing's cross-sectional shape and sometimes to the whole wing.  I think here each separate smaller bladder, when inflated turns the flat cloth into an airfoil by giving it shape in the direction of the chord. (Thus forming the chord). Inflating all the bladders forms the whole airfoil shape (or foil). I would make the analogy: offshoots from the trunk form the branches or canopy of the tree.

Comment: @Jim: I agree that the words denote different concepts. But the use of **or** seems to be illogical if we imagine the sentence treating them as different concepts. The sentence should then use **and**: "the bladder configuration forms the chord **and** foil of the kite".

Comment: I read it as, "bladders [...] to form the chord, or *[in other words, the]* foil of the kite."